# Change messageTimer.Interval at runtime even if the messageTimer is in another method

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatchertimer

I want to change the interval of my dispatcher time in run time
here is my code :

```
InitializeComponent();
        DispatcherTimer messageTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        messageTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(messageTimer_Tick);
        messageTimer.Interval =  TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        messageTimer.Start();
```

idk how to change the interval of the DispatcherTimer at run time

Comment: Set `messageTimer.Interval`, after moving the timer to a field.

Answer (score 0):

I created two textblocks and a button.

1. textblock : x:Name="txt_Count"
2. textblock : x:Name="txt_TimeNow"
3. Button : x:Name="btn_changeTime_s"

   ```
        int count = 0;
        DispatcherTimer messageTimer;
        DispatcherTimer TimeNow;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            messageTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            messageTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(messageTimer_Tick);
            messageTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            messageTimer.Start();

            TimeNow = new DispatcherTimer();
            TimeNow.Tick += new EventHandler(TimeNow_Tick);
            TimeNow.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
            TimeNow.Start();
        }

        private void TimeNow_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txt_now.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }

        private void messageTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txt_Count.Text = count.ToString();
            count++;
        }

        private void btn_changeTime_s_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            messageTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
        }
   ```

If you need to modify the Main UI Thread in the background, use the syntax

```
 txt_Count.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,new Action(delegate ()
              {
                  txt_Count.Text = count.ToString();
              }
              ));
```

Comment: i get an error using this :

CS0649 The 'cpuram.messageTimer' field is never assigned and will always have its default value of null

Comment: Try assigning it to a field or assigning null?

Like this
DispatcherTimer messageTimer = null;

OR
DispatcherTimer messageTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

Comment: The would be because, as the message states, you haven't set (assigned) messageTimer to an instance of a dispatchertimer.

Comment: even after using DispatcherTimer messageTimer = null; i get this error